# How can I generate TouchEvent in JavaFX 2?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8

I am developing a multitouch application, and I will use TUIO-Based approach. When the JavaFX application receives TUIO event, it should translate it into TouchEvent and fire them.

However, the TouchEvent.impl_touchEvent function, which can generate TouchEvents, is deprecated. Also the touchEvent constructor is private, so we cannot create TouchEvent by our own. Is there another way to generate TouchEvent in JavaFX 2.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java 8 event creation in user code is supported by: [RT-9383 Add proper constructors & factory methods to event classes, remove impl](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-9383)

An early access version of Java 8 with this functionality is available for [download](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html).

Comment: thanks, I downloaded JDK 8 and it has public constructor, problem solved!! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can look at my answer on events generating here : [How to send events from one Node to another Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341529/how-to-send-events-from-one-node-to-another-node/16343453#16343453)

Seems, for touch event - you will need to replace on of parameters there.

As a hint - you can download openJFX sources, and look on implementation of according classes.